# React/Vite/Next app works fine in production mode but not dev mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, vite

I am creating a website. I first tried creating it with Next.js, but quickly found out that the responsive navigation bar only worked fine in a production build and not developer mode. In the production build, there is a hamburger icon for smaller devices like iPhones and vertical tablets. For landscape tablets and laptops/desktops, all the navigation items are laid out.

In developer mode, the hamburger icon is always visible regardless of device size. If I open Chrome developer tools and create a custom device with the 1920x1080 dimensions, then the correct navbar will show. Otherwise, I will always be shown the navigation bar. This is going to make it extremely difficult/time consuming for me to test my app periodically while developing it.

I tried moving the navigation bar to a Vite app and a create-react-app application, but the same issue persisted both times.

Here is the code for the navigation bar (created with Material UI).

```
"use client"; //only for Next.js
import { useState } from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import StarIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Star';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';

const pages = ['Home', 'About Me', 'Projects', 'Skills', 'Awards'];
const urls = ["/", "about", "projects", "skills", "awards"];

interface Props {
  window?: () => Window;
}

const Navigation = (props: Props) => {
  // const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = useState(null);

  // const handleOpenNavMenu = (event) => {
  //   setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
  // };

  // const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
  //   setAnchorElNav(null);
  // };

  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    setMobileOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  const { window } = props;

  const drawer = (
    <Box onClick={handleDrawerToggle} sx={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
      <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ my: 2 }}>
        FirstName LastName
      </Typography>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {pages.map((item, key) => (
            <ListItem disablePadding key={item}>
              <ListItemButton sx={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <ListItemText primary={item} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </Box>
  );

  const container = window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;

  return (
    <AppBar position="sticky">
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
          <StarIcon sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' }, mr: 1 }} />
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component="a"
            href="/"
            sx={{
              mr: 2,
              display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' },
              fontFamily: 'monospace',
              fontWeight: 700,
              letterSpacing: '.2rem',
              color: 'inherit',
              textDecoration: 'none',
            }}
          >
            FirstName LastName
          </Typography>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' } }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls="menu-appbar"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Drawer
              container={container}
              variant="temporary"
              open={mobileOpen}
              onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
              ModalProps={{
                keepMounted:true
              }}
              sx={{
            display: { xs: 'block', sm: 'none' },
            '& .MuiDrawer-paper': { boxSizing: 'border-box', width: 240 }
          }}
            >
              {drawer}
            </Drawer>
          </Box>
          <Typography
            variant="body2"
            noWrap
            component="a"
            href=""
            sx={{
              mr: 2,
              display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' },
              flexGrow: 1,
              fontFamily: 'monospace',
              fontWeight: 700,
              letterSpacing: '.1rem',
              color: 'inherit',
              textDecoration: 'none',
            }}
          >
            FirstName LastName
          </Typography>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
            {pages.map((page, key) => (
              <Button
                key={page}
                onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
                sx={{ my: 2, color: 'white', display: 'block' }}
              >
                  {page}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </Box>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
              <IconButton sx={{ p: 0 }}>
                <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="photo.jpg" />
              </IconButton>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
export default Navigation;
```

Anyone know how I can get the developer/local mode of React/Vite/Next.js to correctly display the correct navigation bar as per the screen size? Again, the production build (once deployed) has no issues, just not the developer/local mode.

Thank you.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).